# Djikstra modification to get amount of shortest path from point to point

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

i have task to count amount of shortest path from vertex to vertex in undirected weight graph. I decided to use djikstra algorithm and i got implementation and it properly solving problem and it gives me shortest path. I read that i have to modify queue to solve my problem but when i counting path there like that.

```
        while vertices:
            current_vertex = min(
                vertices, key=lambda vertex: distances[vertex]
            )
            vertices.remove(current_vertex)
            if distances[current_vertex] == inf:
                break
            for neighbour, cost in self.neighbours[current_vertex]:
                alternative_route = distances[current_vertex] + cost
                if alternative_route < distances[neighbour]:
                    distances[neighbour] = alternative_route
                    shortestPaths += 1
                    previous_vertices[neighbour] = current_vertex
```

But it doesnt work and i got inproper count of that shortestPaths. I'll be really thankfull for some tips or solution ;).

Thank You in advance

```
from collections import deque, namedtuple



inf = float('inf')
Edge = namedtuple('Edge', 'start, end, cost')


def make_edge(start, end, cost=1):
  return Edge(start, end, cost)


class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges, both_ends=True):
        # let's check that the data is right
        wrong_edges = [i for i in edges if len(i) not in [2, 3]]
        if wrong_edges:
            raise ValueError('Wrong edges data: {}'.format(wrong_edges))
        self.edges = []
        for edge in edges:
            self.add_edge(*edge, both_ends)

    @property
    def vertices(self):
        return set(
            sum(
                ([edge.start, edge.end] for edge in self.edges), []
            )
        )

    def get_node_pairs(self, n1, n2, both_ends=True):
        if both_ends:
            node_pairs = [[n1, n2], [n2, n1]]
        else:
            node_pairs = [[n1, n2]]
        return node_pairs

    def remove_edge(self, n1, n2, both_ends=True):
        node_pairs = self.get_node_pairs(n1, n2, both_ends)
        edges = self.edges[:]
        for edge in edges:
            if [edge.start, edge.end] in node_pairs:
                self.edges.remove(edge)

    def add_edge(self, n1, n2, cost=1, both_ends=True):
        node_pairs = self.get_node_pairs(n1, n2, both_ends)
        for edge in self.edges:
            if [edge.start, edge.end] in node_pairs:
                return ValueError('Edge {} {} already exists'.format(n1, n2))

        self.edges.append(Edge(start=n1, end=n2, cost=cost))
        if both_ends:
            self.edges.append(Edge(start=n2, end=n1, cost=cost))

    @property
    def neighbours(self):
        neighbours = {vertex: set() for vertex in self.vertices}
        for edge in self.edges:
            neighbours[edge.start].add((edge.end, edge.cost))

        return neighbours

    def dijkstra(self, source, dest):
        assert source in self.vertices, 'Such source node doesn\'t exist'
        distances = {vertex: inf for vertex in self.vertices}
        previous_vertices = {
            vertex: None for vertex in self.vertices
        }
        distances[source] = 0
        vertices = self.vertices.copy()

        while vertices:
            current_vertex = min(
                vertices, key=lambda vertex: distances[vertex]
            )
            vertices.remove(current_vertex)
            if distances[current_vertex] == inf:
                break
            for neighbour, cost in self.neighbours[current_vertex]:
                alternative_route = distances[current_vertex] + cost
                if alternative_route < distances[neighbour]:
                    distances[neighbour] = alternative_route
                    previous_vertices[neighbour] = current_vertex

        path, current_vertex = deque(), dest

        while previous_vertices[current_vertex] is not None:
            path.appendleft(current_vertex)
            current_vertex = previous_vertices[current_vertex]
        if path:
            path.appendleft(current_vertex)
        return path

graph = Graph([
    (1, 3, 2),  (1, 4, 2),  (3, 4 ,3), (1, 5, 12),
    (4, 2, 34), (5, 2, 24)]
)

print(graph.dijkstra(1,2))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
"It doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea that comes to my mind is taking the working implementation which only return the shortest path, and count the number of route to each vertex while propagating.

I am not sure if this idea is matematicly correct though.

NB: you can Ctrl+F `number_of_routes` to find my modifications)

```py
def dijkstra(self, source, dest):
    assert source in self.vertices, 'Such source node doesn\'t exist'
    distances = {vertex: inf for vertex in self.vertices}
    number_of_routes = {vertex: 0 for vertex in self.vertices}
    previous_vertices = {
        vertex: None for vertex in self.vertices
    }
    distances[source] = 0
    number_of_routes[source] = 1
    vertices = self.vertices.copy()

    while vertices:
        current_vertex = min(
            vertices, key=lambda vertex: distances[vertex]
        )
        vertices.remove(current_vertex)
        if distances[current_vertex] == inf:
            break
        for neighbour, cost in self.neighbours[current_vertex]:
            alternative_route = distances[current_vertex] + cost
            if alternative_route < distances[neighbour]:
                distances[neighbour] = alternative_route
                previous_vertices[neighbour] = current_vertex
                number_of_routes[neighbour] = number_of_routes[current_vertex]
                    # reset the counter as the previous routes were not optimal
            elif alternative_route == distances[neighbour]:
                number_of_routes[neighbour] += number_of_routes[current_vertex]

    path, current_vertex = deque(), dest

    while previous_vertices[current_vertex] is not None:
        path.appendleft(current_vertex)
        current_vertex = previous_vertices[current_vertex]
    if path:
        path.appendleft(current_vertex)
    return path, number_of_routes[dest]
```

Comment: That work's ! Thank You. One thing which i edited is that resetting the counter should be marked as 1 cuz selected path should be counted too ! Thank You :) !

Comment: ```graph = Graph([
    (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1), (3, 7, 1), (7, 4, 1),
    (7, 5, 1), (6, 7, 1), (5, 2, 1), (6, 2, 1)]
)```

Unfortunatelly i found the case when it doesn't work. As i saw that line 
`elif alternative_route == distances[neighbour]` is never true :(. Maybe it happends because graph is undirected and all weight is 1 ?

Answer from algorithm is 1, but correct one is 4.

Comment: Wow, you are right, my answer is completely wrong! It only works if the alternative routes merges in the end. When the algorithm progress in the graph, you would need to keep track of the alternative routes for each node, so that it propagates...

Comment: Actually, I dived in your code and tried my last comment idea. I discovered that the graph `Graph([ (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1), (3, 7, 1), (7, 4, 1), (7, 5, 1), (6, 7, 1), (5, 2, 1), (6, 2, 1)] )` was not undirected: you made `both_ends=True` the default for your method `Graph.add_edge`, but you bypassed this method in your `Graph.__init__`.
After this small correction, my idea worked on your example. I edited your questions with the correct constructor.

Comment: Yea i agreed that its bypassed but after the change of __init__ i still have 2 as the answer :(.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205558/discussion-between-piotrek332-and-raphael).

Comment: And edited my answer :) I also added a disclaimer because I am not 100% sure my method is correct. You might want to look at implementations of dijkstra [which return all the shortest pahs](https://www.google.com/search?q=dijkstra+all+possible+shortest+paths&oq=dijkstra+all+possible+shortest+paths)